# Compare phrases in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

How can I compare 2 phrases in PostgreSQL, omitting word-forms? I tried to test Full text features:

```
select ts_rank(to_tsvector('eat apple'), phraseto_tsquery('eating apples'))
```

I expected to get rank 100%, but got 0.0991032. Is there any other type of queries to check that "eat apple" completely matches "eating apples"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ts_rank()` is not meant to check for complete equality. It's a simple ranking function that basically just counts the number of matches in a document. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING)

> Ranks vectors based on the frequency of their matching lexemes.

Consider:

```
select ts_rank(to_tsvector('eat apple'), phraseto_tsquery('eating apples'))
     , ts_rank(to_tsvector('xxx eat apple yyy'), phraseto_tsquery('eating apples'))
     , ts_rank(to_tsvector('eat apple eat apple'), phraseto_tsquery('eating apples'))
     , ts_rank(to_tsvector('eat apple eat apple eat apple'), phraseto_tsquery('eating apples'))
     , ts_rank(to_tsvector('eat apple eat apple eat apple eat apple eat apple eat apple eat apple eat apple eat apple'), phraseto_tsquery('eating apples'));
```

The rank is highest for the last expression just because there are many matches. The first two share the same rank.

> Is there any other type of queries to check that "eat apple" completely matches "eating apples"?

You could compare two `tsvecor` values for equality:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('eat apple') = to_tsvector('eating apples');
```

To be sure (and not depend on current locale settings), spell out the text search configuration:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'eat apple') = to_tsvector('english', 'eating apples')
```

Returns `true` for an exact match.
Not supported by a text search indexes, though, which only support the operators `@@`, `@@@`, `<@`, and `@>`. You could combine both. Like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  to_tsvector(text_field) @@ phraseto_tsquery('eating apples')  -- with index support
ORDER  BY to_tsvector(text_field) <> to_tsvector('eating apples')  -- exact match first
        , ts_rank(to_tsvector(text_field), phraseto_tsquery('eating apples')) DESC
```

Sorts exact matches first because `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`.

Comment: whats wrong with ts_rank(to_tsvector(text_field) <> phraseto_tsquery('eating apples')) ? I've got error operator does not exist: tsvector <> tsquery

Comment: @Molfar: Sorry, there was a typo; now fixed.